# What is the better way to work with the imported JSON data in a react component?

Tags: json, reactjs

In React component is it better to render JSON as an imported file or it's more convenient to work with JSON data after assigning it to the local state? Considering that I'm not planning to mutate it in anyway. Just render as a list for example.

```
import jsonData from 'src/data.json'
```

or

```
import jsonData from 'src/data.json'

const [data, setData] = useState(null)

setData(jsonData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component might need to change some of the data while running, state is definitely the right choice, because you don't want to mutate the import, and because you'd want data change to result in render change.

If the data is absolutely constant and you don't see any need for functionality that changes it, feel free to use the plain `import` alone. There's nothing stopping you from also putting the import into state, but in such a case, since the state will never change, there's not much point to state.